# Solving $\iint_{[0,1]^2}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2})^3}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Solving $$\iint_{[0,1]^2}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2})^3}$$

Thinking of using $$x=r\cos\varphi \\ y=r\sin\varphi \\ J=r$$ But this is a square, so I just, am guessing need to find the range of $r$, what it is, and why?

Comment: This is a Riemann integral? You're missing your differential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to symmetry, this is $2 \int_0^1 \int_0^x (1 + x^2+y^2)^{-3/2} dy \, dx$. In polar coordinates the integration domain may be described by the inequalities $0 \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{4}, \, 0 \le r \le \sec \theta$. Thus the integral now becomes
$$
\int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{\sec \theta} r(1+r^2)^{-3/2} dr \, d \theta
$$ 
The rest is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Hans, I believe that the upper limit is $\sec(\theta)$, not $\tan (\theta)$.  And you dropped the factor of $2$.  ;-)) -Mark

Comment: Why exactly does $r$range from $0$ to $\sec \theta$?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic: because we are over a square.